# jQuery sliding box with caption, the caption starts on top on page-load

Tags: jquery

Pretty new to this with jQuery. I´m using a plugin to animate jQuery sliding box with caption.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){


                $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
                    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'130px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
                }, function() {
                    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'190px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The problem is that when page-loads the caption position at the top in each div-container. 
But I want the caption at the bottom just showing the name on "page-load". 
http://www.missbee.se/myPerformance3/

And here is the plugin page,
http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/sliding-doors/

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css in line 72

change

```
.caption .boxcaption {
    left: 0;
    top: 190;
}
```

to

```
.caption .boxcaption {
    left: 0;
    top: 190px;
}
```

just `'px'` is missing

Comment: Thanx Uttara for your great help!